# Can this iteration through a XML be rewritten?

Tags: php, optimization

I have below code to iterate through a xml file.

```
$nodelist = $xml->getElementsByTagName('cv');
foreach ($nodelist as $node) {
   $naam = $node->getElementsByTagName('naam');
   $naamid = $naam->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

It there a way to get the value in one line?

```
$nodelist = $xml->getElementsByTagName('cv');
foreach ($nodelist as $node) {
   $naamid = <a one line to get the nodevalue of naam out of the  xml>;
}
```

Comment: $naamid = $node->getElementsByTagName('naam')->item(0)->nodeValue; ??

Comment: Yep, that is working. thank you

Comment: Why did somebody voted me down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could even do the entire program on one line, using Generators you could create a one-liner function which gets all instances of the `naam` element:

```
// Returns a generator which gets all elements with 'naam'
function getNaamElements()
{
    foreach ($xml->getElementsByTagName('cv') as $node) 
    {
        yield $node->getElementsByTagName('naam')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    }
}

// To get an array:
$array = iterator_to_array(getNaamElements());

// To loop over all 'naam' elements in another loop, use the generator instead
foreach (getNaamElements() as $naam)
{
    // Do stuff with $naam
}
```